# SQLにおける欠損値NAへの対処法について

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

いつもお世話になっております。
普段はRのみで統計処理しているのですが、少々大きいデータを処理する必要があり、Postgresqlを使っています。ですが、欠損が多いデータでありNAが多くあり、intで型を指定するとテーブルにインポートできません。（NA以外は数値データです。）
普段はRなのでデータフレームで処理できるのですが今回はそうも行きません。（SQLiteだとスムーズに行くのでしょうか？）
どのように対処すべきかご教示願います。

Comment: PostgreSQL の場合、R の `NA` に相当するのは `NaN` で、`NaN` が使える型は `number`, `decimal`, `real`, `double precision` になっています。PostgreSQL にインポートする際に `NA` を `NaN` に変換してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: realを用いてNaNにしたところ無事解決しました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: @user9156 欠損値を表すのは、NaN (Not a Number) ではなく NULL ではないでしょうか? 欠損値としては、NULL を利用するのが妥当かと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[user9156さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26752/sql%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E6%AC%A0%E6%90%8D%E5%80%A4na%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6?rq=1#comment25504_26752)より引用：

> PostgreSQL の場合、R の `NA` に相当するのは `NaN` で、`NaN` が使える型は `number`, `decimal`, `real`, `double precision` になっています。PostgreSQL にインポートする際に `NA` を `NaN` に変換してみてはいかがでしょうか。